# How do I get jar file of webgoat

Tags: linux, security

I want to learn cyber security and I started with webgoat(On youtube). It says that you should donwnload a jar file from github.com. But I am not able to get the jar file on https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/releases

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a while ago they stopped producing the jar file. Latest build with one is https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/releases/tag/v8.1.0

If you want to use 8.2.0 look at building the source detailed https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat

Comment: Hey I am not able to get that file